# How to remove target id from selected term reference field

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

While selecting taxonomy from autocomplete term reference field, its target id also get displayed. How to remove target id from display?[image]

In picture displayed, I want only 23456789 not bracket part i.e. (19) from display.

Comment: Be careful, Drupal use (19)  because it's the ID of your term, I think you should let him

Answer (score 0):

You need alter autocomplete js like this

```
 function theme_name_js_alter(&$javascript, 
  \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  $path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $path_args = explode('/', $path);
   if($path_args[1] == 'twc-partners'){
   //kint($javascript);
     $javascript['core/misc/autocomplete.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name') . '/js/autocomplete-custom.js';
 } 
}
```

This code add in theme file .Please download file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7gg8zik2m3tjn0d/autocomplete-custom.js?dl=0).